# Laptop battery constantly showing as discharging after upgrading to 17.10

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

I upgraded to 17.10 and realised that the orange (AC power) light on my Acer Aspire v17 was not on when plugged in. Instead there were two blue lights as though is was unplugged. I monitored this whilst plugged in and unplugged. I have found that if the charge level falls below a certain level (not sure exactly where the threshold is) eg. below 95%, I can plug it in and the orange light comes on and the battery shows to be charging (in power statistics). Once back up to the threshold point the orange light goes off but the laptop charges up to 100% even though the battery is shown to be discharging? My understanding is that the battery charge is not controlled by the OS, so is it just coincidence that this started after upgrading or is there something I can do to debug this and fix it?